# What's differents between hasMany associations and Ext.data.Store

Tags: extjs

What's differents between hasMany associations and Ext.data.Store ?

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',  type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User'
});
var user = Ext.create('User', {
    id: 1, name: 'Eugene'
});
myStore.add(user);
alert(myStore.count());
```

ex2:hasMany

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('Company', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
        name: 'Title',
        type: 'string'
        },{
        name: 'Date',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'd-m-Y'
        }, {
        name: 'Value',
        type: 'int'
        }],
        associations: [{
        type: 'hasMany',
        model: 'Manager',
        name: 'founders'
        }]
    });

    Ext.define('Manager', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
        name: 'FirstName',
        type: 'string'
        }, {
        name: 'LastName',
        type: 'string'
        }]
    });
    var company = Ext.create('Company', {
        Title: 'Microsoft',
        Date: '01-01-1974',
        Value: 30000
    });
    company.founders().add({
                FirstName: 'Bill',
                LastName: 'Gates'
                }, {
                FirstName: 'Paul',
                LastName: 'Allen'
            });
    company.founders().each(function (founder){
        alert(founder.get('FirstName') + " "+founder.get('LastName'));
    });
});
```

Why create a new mechanism for the bad ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing the two to be honest, They are completly different things.

**Store**

An ExtJs store is basically a clever array, allows you to maintain a list/collection of models. To quote the documentation:

> The Store class encapsulates a client side cache of Model objects.
> Stores load data via a Proxy, and also provide functions for sorting,
> filtering and querying the model instances contained within it.
>
> Models are typically used with a Store, which is basically a
> collection of records (instances of a Model-derived class).

Example: Store companies contains 20 company models, like so:

Companies:

- Company 1
- ...
- Company 20

**HasMany Association**

HasMany is an association on a model, very similar to a relational database. So you may have a Company Model and a Employees Model for example. A company can have many employees.

> Models can be linked together with the Associations API. Most
> applications deal with many different Models and the Models are almost
> always related. A blog authoring application might have models for
> User and Post. Each User creates Posts. So in this case, a user can
> have multiple posts, but a post will only have one User creating it.
> This is known as a ManyToOne relationship.

When you combine these two things you can have a list of models and all their related records to hand. So for a basic code example (psuedo code), you might do something like:

```
var companies = new App.stores.Companies(); // here is your collection of companies

companies.each(function(company) {
    var employees = company.employees(); // here is where your hasMany comes in
    // for each employee give a pay rise or something...
});
```

**Side Note**: Associations in ExtJs are not without their issues, they can be limited in functionality and quite difficult to get right. Alot of people tend to have issues with them at first, See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extjs+associations).

The [data package](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/data_package.html) guide in the Sencha Docs explains it all very well, which has also been the source for the quotes above.

Hope this helps